# How to avoid typescript error: Property 'innerHTML' does not exist on type 'Element'

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to place some HTML inside a specific div.  When I try this in typescript I get this error:  `Property 'innerHTML' does not exist on type 'Element'`.   Basicly, this is the code:

```
document.body.innerHTML = '<div id="myDiv"><div>'

let myContainer = document.querySelector("#myDiv");
myContainer.innerHTML = '<h1>Test</h1>';
```

Amazingly, it still works when typescripts compiles,  but I'm wondering if typescript is giving me an error, what's the right way to go on assigning innerHTML in this case?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Use a type assertion to placate the compiler:

```
let myContainer = <HTMLElement> document.querySelector("#myDiv");
myContainer.innerHTML = '<h1>Test</h1>';
```

Comment: If it's not a single element, you can use `<HTMLCollection>`

Comment: What would the 'as' syntax look like for this?

Comment: @Jordan `(document.querySelector('#myDiv') as HTMLElement).innerText = `

Comment: It's no longer a valid answer for latest release

Answer (score 13):

In future versions of TypeScript, it should not be necessary to do the casting. I've sent a pull request to fix the issue:

- `error: Property 'innnerHTML' does not exist on type 'Element'` (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5754)
- https://github.com/Microsoft/TSJS-lib-generator/pull/35 (merged already)

Comment: I did yesterday but still asking for type :(

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue, solved it by declaring it as:

```
myString = 'hello world';

var el: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('id_of_element');
el.innerHTML = myString;
```

Answer (score 5):

The only type-safe way to modify DOM elements is to verify they exist first. TypeScript is smart enough to tell you that `document.querySelector` can return `null` when the target is not found in the document.

```
document.body.innerHTML = '<div id="myDiv"><div>'

let myContainer: HTMLDivElement | null = document.querySelector("#myDiv");

if (myContainer instanceof HTMLDivElement) {
    myContainer.innerHTML = '<h1>Test</h1>';
}
```

The above code compiles without error in TypeScript 3.2.1.

Comment: The error message in the question is not related to `null`: "Property 'innerHTML' does not exist on type 'Element'". The problem is that `document.querySelector` returns an `Element`, which may or may not be a `HTMLElement`. Testing for `null`ness is not sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

`Use like this (<HTMLElement>document.querySelector("#myDiv")).innerHTML`

Answer (score 2):

1. let myContainer = document.querySelector("#myDiv") as HTMLElement;
2. let myContainer = document.querySelector("#myDiv");
3. let myContainer : HTMLElement = document.querySelector("#myDiv");

Parse your element like this and you should be able to insert whatever you want in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  const onChange = (e: React.SyntheticEvent ) => {\\e: React.SyntheticEvent - if you use ReactJS
    setActive((e.target as HTMLElement).innerHTML); \\innerHTML works fine instead of getInnerHTML() in TypeScript
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

In react you can use

```
const handler = (e: SyntheticEvent) => {
     console.log(e.currentTarget.innerHTML)
}
```