# add a property ton an existing class

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function that takes as argument

```
event: MouseEvent
```

than in my code if I do

```
event.srcElement.innerText;
```

intelisense tells me

> [ts] Property 'innerText' does not exist on type 'Element'.

although the property does exist.

How can I add property `innerText` to `MouseEvent` withthout creating a new class that extends `MouseEvent` ?

Comment: Check this one May be this is helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35252872/how-to-avoid-typescript-error-property-innerhtml-does-not-exist-on-type-elem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast it to `HTMLElement`:

```
(event.srcElement as HTMLElement).innerText;
```

Or modify your function declaration to specify that `srcElement` is `HTMLElement`:

```
function test(event: MouseEvent & {
    srcElement: HTMLElement
}) {
    event.srcElement.innerText;
}
```

The parameter `event` is an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) now.