# Angular 7 HTTP Requests with Basic Authentication

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, basic-authentication

I am using angular 7 with Spring Boot and Spring Security. I implement the basic authentication in Back End

The problem I have is I send request from Angular with Http Header containing User name and Password. But in back end throws an exception called 'The request was rejected because the URL was not normalized'. 
How can I solve this?

This is the Request

```
const httpOptions = {
   headers: new HttpHeaders({
     'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('test:test123')
   })
 };

 return this.http.get(this.url+"/items",httpOptions);
```

Comment: org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL was not normalized.

Comment: This is not an Angular problem. it seems some firewall is there which is blocking. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35252872/how-to-avoid-typescript-error-property-innerhtml-does-not-exist-on-type-elem

Comment: I check this using Postman. It works!

Comment: I disagree that this is typo/no-repo. It is, however, lacking a [MCVE], because it doesn't tell us that `this.url` is, which is critical to determining the actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that `this.url` does not have a trailing slash, because if so then you will get double slashes before `item` which is a common cause of this is "URL was not normalized" error.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed it. But now in Front End shows an HTTP Error. Code 401

Comment: This means that the user is unauthenticated which means that the basic authorization was not successful for some reason. can you share your Security Configuration.

Comment: I just added Security dependency to pom.xml and added user name and password to the application.property file.

Comment: I send a request using postman with basic authentication, It works, But using angular it doesn't works

Comment: Can you try to check the `Authorization` header value in the Request Headers from developer tools and compare it to the value from the headers in PostMan and see if they match or not

Comment: I checked it. In  browser shows like this 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization'. In postman shows like 'authorization": "Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0MTIz'

Comment: I think you're looking at the wrong header, the header you should be looking for has the key `Authorization` and not `Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization`

Comment: also it is under the Request Headers not Response Headers

Comment: I checked again. That kind of key not found.

Comment: I believe your issue is related to CORS support of the server, by default sending credentials to cross domain origin is not allowed for obvious security reasons. Make sure that the server is allowing cross site requests and allowing credentials

Comment: I removed security dependency and again check it. In that time  the requests header has `Authorization`

Comment: yes that's because the default security config is not to allow the inclusion of credentials in cross site requests

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I will go through above details